# Unknown provider: userProvider for existing Yeoman AngularFire user service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularfire, yeoman-generator

I'm having some trouble injecting a service into a controller in a Yeoman AngularFire app.

Here is the controller(which is included by the Yeoman generator) that I am trying to inject `user` into:

```
angular.module('myYoApp')
      .controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, user, Ref, $firebaseArray, $timeout) { ....
```

Which produces this `Unknown provider` error:

```
angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user <- ChatCtrl
```

Strangely it works fine in my custom controller, allowing the user to be accessed in the associated view.

```
angular.module('myYoApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, user, Auth, Ref, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $timeout) { ....
```

I have no idea why the `user` service would be injectable in my custom controller but not in the Yeoman generated `ChatCtrl`. I've also looked all over the project and can't seem to find where the `user` service is coming from. But it's clearly somewhere in the app if my custom service can use it.

I've also tried using `$user` in place of `user` but that didn't fix it.
Cheers for any help figuring this out!

Comment: If the myCtrl isn't created you won't see the error about the user service where are you expecting the user service to come from?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by if the myCtrl isn't created. Regarding where I expect the user service to come from, I don't know but I expect it to come from somewhere as services usually do come from a separate file and are then injected into the modules where they are required. In any case, the user has to be accessible somehow in order to be used throughout the app, no?

Comment: I tried removing myCtrl and all references to it completely but still getting the error when injecting the user into the ChatCtrl. Thanks for suggestion all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.I managed to solve this. It was an oversight in the `routes.js`. The Yeoman angularfire-generator adds built-in routes security/authentication which is added to a route to easily block it from being accessed unless the user is logged in. 
As a result, the `user` service can only be injected into a controller if the route uses `$routeProvider.whenAuthenticated` in place of `$routeProvider.when`.

Regular unsecured route looks like this:

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
```

Secured route looks like this:

```
 $routeProvider
  .whenAuthenticated('/chat', {
        templateUrl: 'views/chat.html',
        controller: 'ChatCtrl'
      })
```